# High Charts xAxis first label repeating on all ticks

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highchart to create a chart. I am using xAxis type: 'datetime'

my first xAxis label is showing repeatedly. When i add tickInterval all graph ticks overlaps on one and another, So i used pointInterval instead. All graph options are working except first xAxis label which is showing repeatedly.

here is my options js:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'area'},
        title: {text: null},
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            labels: {
                padding: 0,
                step: 1,
                formatter : function() {
                    var dayStr = Highcharts.dateFormat('%a ',this.value);
                    return dayStr;
                }
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: <?php echo $this_min;?>,
            max: <?php echo $this_max;?>,
            title: { text:'mmHg' }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{showInLegend: false, name:'diastolic', data:[[1464998400, 130], [1465171200, 125], [1465344000, 120], [1465430400, 122]]}, {showInLegend: false, name:'systolic', data:[[1464998400, 90], [1465171200, 85], [1465344000, 80], [1465430400, 82]]}],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = [];

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s.push('<span style="font-weight:bold;">'+point.y +'<span>');
                });

                return s.join('/')+' mmHg';
            },
            shared: true
        },
        credits: { enabled: false}
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I think that right now you are not really using pointInterval because you are using your custom x values. Additionally pointInterval is parameter used inside plotOptions object. Here you can see an example how you can make your chart using pointInterval:http://jsfiddle.net/vuv2rkoa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/a8pp300g/5/).

The timestamp `[1464998400, 1465171200, 1465344000, 1465430400]` that you used in `series` is pointing to the same date which is `Jan 18 1970` and that's why your x-axis label seems repeating. Check out my modified code @line#54 and the label is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`pointInterval` is no longer available in the new version of Highchart. You should use [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval) instead.